# Change date format in Catalyst template

Tags: perl, catalyst

My html view is

```
<input type="text" value="[%mortgage.first_payment_date%]" disabled/>
```

Where `[%mortgage.first_payment_date%]` shows date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

I need the date to be in `mm-dd-yyyy` format.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Catalyst, it's do with Template Toolkit and whatever your date is (a string? an object? if so, of what type?)

Answer (score 0):

@Jitesh: Check if this is helpful:

```
<input type="text" value="[% mortgage.first_payment_date.mdy('-') %]" disabled/>
```

Comment: That would only work if the object is a DateTime instance. https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#dt-ymd-optional_separator-dt-mdy-...-dt-dmy

Comment: Even then it doesn't give what the question asked for. They need `mdy()`, not `dmy()`.

Comment: @Dave Cross : Sorry it was mdy() only not dmy() . I was thinking dd-mm-yyyy but it should be mm-dd-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Let's make some rearrangement:

```
[% ymd = mortgage.first_payment_date.split('-') %]
[% mdy = [ymd.1, ymd.2, ymd.0].join('-') %]

<input type="text" value="mdy" disabled/>
```